# Migrating from h:commandButton to h:button

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I want to change the h:commandButton to h:button component . I am confused how the work the action listener does can be achieved by h:button . Is it possible to migrate with all the functions working .

```
<h:commandButton id="upldDoc"
                disabled="#{triggerRequestFormBean.disableDocUpload}"  
                actionListener="#triggerRequestFormBean.docUploadListener}"
                partialSubmit ="true"
                onclick ="pageRefresh();"
                value="Load" styleClass="buttonStyle" 
                title="Load" />
```

Comment: There is no `partialSubmit` attribute with `h:commandButton` or `h:button` for that matter

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused how the work the action listener does can be achieved by h:button. Is it possible to migrate with all the functions working

No you cannot. `h:button` element does not trigger BackingBean actions. You will have to remain with the `h:commandButton` if you want to achieve it.